# Segmentation fault with ADT

Tags: c, data-structures, typedef

This gives me a segmentation fault error. Any ideas why?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
    typedef struct {
    int *items;
    int length;
 } IntArray;

 void init(IntArray *I)
 {
// I->length = 0;       
 I->items = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
 I->items[0] = 1;

    } 
      int main()
   {
   IntArray *i;
      init(i);
   return 0;}
```

I thought maybe I did everything right except declaring the IntArray in main, wasn't sure how exactly I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
int main()
{
    IntArray *i;    // uninitialised pointer

    init(i);
    return 0;
}
```

`i` is uninitialised. It points nowhere. When you pass this pointer to `init` and dereference it via `i->items`, you get a segmentation violation.

Instead of creating a pointer, you can create a struct object and pass its address:

```
int main()
{
    IntArray i;      // uninitialised object

    init(&i);        // valid address to said object
    return 0;
}
```

The object itself is also uninitialised, i.e. its fields contain garbage, but you will fix that in `init`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I had a feeling this was the error but being new to C I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

the parameter `i` being passed into `init(IntArray *I)` is not defined in `main()` prior to the function call, leading to undefined behavior when `I->items` is assigned.

Undefined behavior meaning your seg fault, in this case.